# Using continious dictation

Tags: uwp

Everything is working fine, I just can figure out how to keep my dictation session alive, until I press the button again, because what is happening now is that if I stop speaking for 10 seconds and start speaking again, it will overwrite what I had, so I want to be able to stop the session only when I press the button again

```
  case "0":
                isListening = true;
                var dictationConstraint = new SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint(SpeechRecognitionScenario.Dictation, "dictation");
                speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(dictationConstraint);
                SpeechRecognitionCompilationResult result = await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
                speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.Completed += ContinuousRecognitionSession_Completed;
                speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated += ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated;
                speechRecognizer.HypothesisGenerated += SpeechRecognizer_HypothesisGenerated;
                if (isListening) {
                    await speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
                    textToSpeech.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources[ON];
                }
                break;
            case "1":
                if (richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Bold == FormatEffect.On) {
                    richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Bold = FormatEffect.Off;
                    FormatBoltText.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources[OFF];
                } else {
                    richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Bold = FormatEffect.On;
                    FormatBoltText.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources[ON];
                }
                break;
            case "2":
                if (richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Italic == FormatEffect.On) {
                    richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Italic = FormatEffect.Off;
                    formatItalicText.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources[OFF];
                } else {
                    richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Italic = FormatEffect.On;
                    formatItalicText.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources[ON];
                }
                break;
            case "3":
                if (richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Underline == UnderlineType.Single) {
                    richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Underline = UnderlineType.None;
                    formatUnderlineText.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources[OFF];
                } else {
                    richEbitBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Underline = UnderlineType.Single;
                    formatUnderlineText.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources[ON];
                }
                break;
            case "4":
                if (Ink_cnvas.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed) {
                    formatDraw.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources[ON];
                    Ink_cnvas.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    richEbitBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                } else if (Ink_cnvas.Visibility == Visibility.Visible) {
                    Ink_cnvas.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    formatDraw.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources[OFF];
                    richEbitBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                break;
            case "5":
                richEbitBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.AdjustCrlf, out string value);
                speak(value);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private async void SpeechRecognizer_HypothesisGenerated(SpeechRecognizer sender, SpeechRecognitionHypothesisGeneratedEventArgs args) {
        string hypothesis = args.Hypothesis.Text;
        string textboxContent = dictateBuilder.ToString() + " " + hypothesis + " ...";

        await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            richEbitBox.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, textboxContent);
        });
    }

    private async void ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated(SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs args) {
        await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
            richEbitBox.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.None, args.Result.Text);
        });
    }

    private async void ContinuousRecognitionSession_Completed(SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionCompletedEventArgs args) {
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, when I hit the button again, I get this weird exception: "The text associated with this error coud not be found". by the way the dictation future is on case "0"

Answer (score 0):

> Using continious dictation

Through a simple check, I found that you are missing some code. If you want to using dictation pleas add the following code.

```
var dictationConstraint = new SpeechRecognitionTopicConstraint(SpeechRecognitionScenario.Dictation, "dictation");
speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(dictationConstraint);
```

And we have complete sample could be used, please check SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis code sample [`Scenario_ContinuousDictation`](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis/cs/Scenario_ContinuousDictation.xaml.cs). I have test and it works well, please integrate this scenario to your app.

**Update**

> for example a start writing "My blue duck has a pony tail " and then I hit space and speak "I want to kill myself". Also I want to stop dictating when I press the button.

It's easy to implement base on official code sample you just use `dictatedTextBuilder` append current textbox's text before `StartAsync`, clear after dictatedTextBuilder after `StopAsync` method like following. And please is official code sample `dictationTextBox` is read only please modify to `IsReadOnly="False"`.

```
public async void ContinuousRecognize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btnContinuousRecognize.IsEnabled = false;
    if (isListening == false)
    {
        // The recognizer can only start listening in a continuous fashion if the recognizer is currently idle.
        // This prevents an exception from occurring.
        if (speechRecognizer.State == SpeechRecognizerState.Idle)
        {
            DictationButtonText.Text = " Stop Dictation";
            cbLanguageSelection.IsEnabled = false;
            hlOpenPrivacySettings.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            discardedTextBlock.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;

            try
            {
                isListening = true;
                dictatedTextBuilder.Append(dictationTextBox.Text);
                await speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if ((uint)ex.HResult == HResultPrivacyStatementDeclined)
                {
                    // Show a UI link to the privacy settings.
                    hlOpenPrivacySettings.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(ex.Message, "Exception");
                    await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
                }

                isListening = false;
                DictationButtonText.Text = " Dictate";
                cbLanguageSelection.IsEnabled = true;

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        isListening = false;
        DictationButtonText.Text = " Dictate";
        cbLanguageSelection.IsEnabled = true;

        if (speechRecognizer.State != SpeechRecognizerState.Idle)
        {
            // Cancelling recognition prevents any currently recognized speech from
            // generating a ResultGenerated event. StopAsync() will allow the final session to 
            // complete.
            try
            {
                await speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StopAsync();

                // Ensure we don't leave any hypothesis text behind
                dictationTextBox.Text = dictatedTextBuilder.ToString();
                dictatedTextBuilder.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(exception.Message, "Exception");
                await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
    }
    btnContinuousRecognize.IsEnabled = true;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help sir. I may need you help one more time, controlling the button and the session. I edited the code, I  also wanted to now if there is a way to keep what the user typed. every time I try to concatenate the text of the RichEdit text,I get the same ting

Comment: Could you explain `same ting`?

Comment: I am sorry that was a typo. What I am aiming for is for example, I want to be able to write whatever I wand and then speak or vise versa and the app would concatenate the text written with the text spoken, for example a start writing "My blue duck has a pony tail " and then I hit space and speak "I want to kill myself". Also I want to stop  dictating when I press the button. I am completely stuck